# Inkscape radial gradient center color visibly different from specified stop color

Tags: color, inkscape, gradient

I use Radial Gradient in Inkscape.
**PROBLEM:** Color at center of radiant is much darker than defined stop color, as shown by red arrow:

[image]

How comes?
How can I make the color at the center to be the one I want?

I thought it was just fading too fast, so I added an intermediate stop with the same color, but as you can see it is really a different color.

Answer (score 1):

My problem was that the object's opacity was set to 75%.

Setting opacity to 100% fixed the problem.

Comment: I was going to answer this :)